# what is the role of NF,NR & i++ in this command?

Tags: awk

While working in a shell file; I got this below line which meaning I couldn't understand..

This is the code:-

```
more a.asc |
   awk 'NR>30 {print $0}'|
   awk '{i=1; while (i<NF+1){print $i; i++ }}'|
   awk '{print '$b' + '$delta'*(NR-1), $1}' >a.txt
```

Kindly help me to understand what is the role of NR,NF& i++ here? and what is the meaning of this entire command??

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should really consider reading the `awk` manual. Even if we answer your questions this time it will not help you with the next ones. Did you at least try to run yourself this pipeline? Did you try to run each term of it separately?

Comment: Please read https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v b="$b" -v delta="$delta" '
  NR>30 {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
          print (b + ((cnt++) * delta)), $i
      }
  }
' a.asc > a.txt
```

Hopefully that's easier to understand without the useless use of `more`, the (potentially dangerous) insertion of shell variables into the code, and the unnecessary `awk|awk|awk`.

On records >30 in the file named "a.asc": print the result of some arithmetic for each field. The shell clobbers "a.txt" with this output (even if there is no output). Presumably the shell variables `$b` and `$delta` (quoted in the shell like `"$b"` and passed through to awk using `-v`) are expected to be numeric.